# remove bracketed section headers from text in r

Tags: r, special-characters

I am trying to remove square brackets containing numbers from my document. Actually the brackets are the headers for each section of the text. I do not want to remove the other numbers because I want the dates.

Below is an example of the text:

```
[285] The woman wore the styles of the 1970s.

[286] The shone brightly on Christmas 1990.

[287] The doctor saw patients for twelve hours.
```

I tried the following but it did not work.

```
for(j in seq(docs))   
   {   
     docs[[j]] <- gsub("[]", " ", docs[[j]])   

  }
```

I would like for the text to look like the following:

```
The woman wore the styles of the 1970s
The shone brightly on Christmas 1990
The doctor saw patients for twelve hours
```

I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: You might want to change your `gsub` command to something like `gsub('^[\\[\\]\\d]+ *', " ", docs[[j]], perl = TRUE)`.  The `"[]"` is not correct.

Comment: Looks like they are print numbers.  Maybe cat(paste(x, collapse = "\n"))

Answer (score 1):

We could try

```
sub("[][]\\d+[][]\\s*", "", v1)
#[1] "The woman wore the styles of the 1970s."   "The shone brightly on Christmas 1990."     "The doctor saw patients for twelve hours."
```

Or

```
sub("^[^[:alpha:]]+\\s+", '', v1)
#[1] "The woman wore the styles of the 1970s."   "The shone brightly on Christmas 1990."     "The doctor saw patients for twelve hours."
```

#### data

```
 v1 <- c("[285] The woman wore the styles of the 1970s.",
 "[286] The shone brightly on Christmas 1990.", 
 "[287] The doctor saw patients for twelve hours.")
```